# Symfony weirdness, missing a trick

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Noticed a big massive loophole in my symfony site. If I visit 
localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/module [naturally the indexSuccess.php file gets executed]
I get the desired file... however, if I go onto:
localhost:8080/module, then it returns a 500 internal server error.

This is obviously going to be a biiiig problem once I migrate to production [heck, I have migrated and it is the problem].

I am sure I am missing a trick here, just what I am not sure!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a real question, but why would you think not including the controller would work?

```
# wrong
localhost:8080/module

# right - By default Controller needs .php extension
localhost:8080/frontend.php/module
```

Also, you can check the 500 internal server error by tailing your php error_log, assuming you have logging turned on.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for responding [again]...but no visiting localhost:8080/frontend/module does not work...returns a 404 error

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the .php extension. Updated post.

Comment: ummm...that should not be the case, symfony urls regardless do not come with a .php extension, they are routed...the issue is probably somethnig else

Comment: Actually that's not true, you have to do some configuration to remove the .php extension from your controllers. Just check to make sure the frontend.php worked as you expected. If so I can post you a link to setting up extensionless controllers.

Comment: I am not sure if I have followed this configuration before, not sure where to find that but feel free to share the link

Comment: I posted an article on my blog on how to remove the extension for dedicated and virtual hosting, let me know how it works for you. http://melikedev.com/2011/06/15/symfony-remove-php-from-controller-using-symlink/

Comment: Did you run `check_configuration.php`? http://symfony-check.org/permalink/check-the-configuration-of-the-production-server

Comment: No. I know that my symfony configuration works, because it works. Check my profile, I have a link to my drink recipe search engine which is written using SF 1.4 and has no .php extension in the controllers.

Comment: @MikePurcell I was asking user1020069 :)

Comment: @j0k: Sorry, thought it was his response.

Comment: Hi Mike, no that strategy did not work. @jOk ...the symfony configuration does work for me, I did run check_configuration.php as well but with little success ...